# Playing multiple video using libvlc and Qt

Tags: qt, libvlc

I have created a sample application in Qt where i have to display camera stream in a 2x2 grid. I am using libvlc to play the stream and i am able to display the video as well. But i am facing few issues

1. Vlc is creating a separate window to render the video. Its not displayed on the area provided by Qt Application.

Here is my code

```
void playerView::createPlayer()
    {
        const char *const vlc_args[] = {
                  "--avcodec-hw=any",
                  "--plugin-path=C:\QtSDK\vlc-2.2.1\plugins" };

        vlcinstance = libvlc_new(sizeof(vlc_args) / sizeof(vlc_args[0]), vlc_args);

        const char* url = "rtsp://<camera ip>/cam0_0";


        /* Create a new LibVLC media descriptor */
        media = libvlc_media_new_location(vlcinstance, url);

        // Create a media player playing environement
        vlcmp = libvlc_media_player_new(vlcinstance);

        libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(vlcmp, (void*)videodisplay->winId());
        libvlc_media_player_set_media(vlcmp, media);
        libvlc_media_player_play (vlcmp);
    }
```

2. As i need to display 3 videos in a 2x2 grid, I am creating 3 vlc player instances to play the video. 2 windows are getting created and video is played. On creating the 3rd one, it crashes with the below error.

   directdraw vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       direct2d vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       Warning: option --plugin-path no longer exists.
       [008ceb04] directdraw vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       [008ceb04] direct2d vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       glwin32 vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       wingdi vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       [008ceb04] glwin32 vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       [008ceb04] wingdi vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)
       core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
       caca vout display error: Unsupported query in vout display caca
       core vout display error: Failed to set on top
       core vout display error: Failed to change source AR
       [008ceb04] core vout display error: Failed to change zoom
       [008ceb04] caca vout display error: Unsupported query in vout display caca
       [008ceb04] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
       [008ceb04] core vout display error: Failed to change source AR
       core vout display error: Failed to set on top
       [H264 Decoder @ 0387aee0] invalid mixed IDR / non IDR frames cannot be decoded in slice multithreading mode
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038b8400] decode_slice_header error
       [H264 Decoder @ 038fd000] invalid mixed IDR / non IDR frames cannot be decoded in slice multithreading mode
       [038c6544] core vout display error: Failed to set on top
       core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
       core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
       [02c4264c] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
       [02c41a1c] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
       core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
       [h264 @ 038c3d00] decode_slice_header error
       [h264 @ 038c3d00] decode_slice_header error
       [H264 Decoder @ 0cb12c40] invalid mixed IDR / non IDR frames cannot be decoded in slice multithreading mode
       [02c427b4] core input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called

   Error is related to GPU and i dont have any idea how to fix this issue using libvlc. Even search doesnt help to find a right solution.

Please show me some light to proceed as i m totally stuck !!

Comment: regarding your first question, have a look at [Player::playFile](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_SampleCode_Qt/)

Comment: i have taken the reference of that link to develope this code. But libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd is not able to render the video in the area provided by my Qt application i.e QWidget

Comment: Please look https://github.com/RSATom/QmlVlcDemo - it's the demo for QmlVlc lib which allow do exaclty what you need with ease (but it will require use QML).

Comment: Thanks RSATom...but i am using Qt4.8 and i dnt think it supports QML. However i went through ur Git contribution, U Seem to be have done so much research on VLC sdk.  Can you please let me know why libvlc is creating separate window rather than displaying it in the Qt Widget ? Can it be a linvlc version problem ?

Comment: All I can say is libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(vlcmp, (HWND)videodisplay->winId()); should work (I use same function in my browser plugin). But as start point you should check if videodisplay->winId() returns real HWND (with Spy++ for example)

Comment: I am not sure if I m missing anything here. But i tried with all versions of libvlc and all examples as well. But not sure why its not taking the QWidget window handle.

Comment: Did you try Spy++? Does your app has any HWND except main window? Does HWND returned from winId is the same as shown in Spy++?

Comment: I am using a QWidget inside the main window where the video should be displayed. I tried Spy++ but i dnt think it gives the handle of the Widget inside Main window

Comment: Please read "Native Widgets vs Alien Widgets" at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html

Comment: Still its not working. In fact its written that "If a widget is non-native (alien) and winId() is invoked on it, that widget will be provided a native handle." Means QWidget::winId will return a native handle. Is it so ?

Comment: How many HWND your application have in Spy++?

Comment: See similar issue here, I posted an answer that may solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320657/libvlc-media-player-set-hwnd-doesnt-work-with-qwidget-handle/31258931#31258931