# LibVlc can't be used in Qt Frame in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, libvlc, directdraw

So I'm trying to embed a few VLC media players into their separate QTFrames. Everything is done in python. However for some reason the official example doesn't want to work (found [here](https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/qtvlc.py;h=28d8925661f110e05fee255bc7d325f266f4cd70;hb=HEAD))

My code looks like this:

```
for files in tutorialVideoFiles:
     #frame = QFrame()
     mediaplayer = vlcInstance.media_player_new()  #create media player
     media = vlcInstance.media_new(mainTutorialDirectory + "/" + self.tutorialName + "/" + files)  #load video file
     mediaplayer.set_media(media)  #assign video file
     media.parse()
     self.mediaplayers.append(mediaplayer)
     #mediaplayer.set_hwnd(frame.winId())
```

If I uncomment the lines, I get the following error:
"directdraw vout display error: Win32VoutCreateWindow RegisterClass FAILED (err=1410)"

I'm using Windows 64 bit and Python 3.6

Comment: Does it work if you do it for a single file rather than for many in a loop?

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I tried a super simple example in a separate file and it worked there. So I assume it has something to do with PyQT setting up the Frame too slowly maybe?

Comment: Possibly. Looks like the same problem here in C++ https://stackoverflow.com/q/30189576 Maybe consider testing the situation where you start with 1 working frame, then add another on a button click. Or maybe setup all the frames first and then add an additional vlc instance each button click.